# Why does Python list comprehension print a list of "None"s in the end?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

From Python 3.6 prompt:

```
>>> [print(i) for i in range(3)]
0
1
2
[None, None, None]
```

Comment: don't use `print` inside list comprehension. Do `print([i for i in range(3)])`

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension creates a list containing the results of evaluating the expression for each iteration. As well as the "side-effect" of printing out whatever you give it, the `print` function returns `None`, so that is what gets stored in the list.

Since you're in an interactive console, the return value is printed out at the end. If you ran this as a script, the output wouldn't include `[None, None, None]`.

If you're wanting to loop over `0`, `1`, `2` and print them out, I'm afraid you have to do it as a proper `for`-loop:

```
for i in range(3)
    print(i)
```

Though I fully empathise with the desire to use the neat one-line syntax of a list comprehension!

---

As other people have commented, you can achieve the same effect by constructing the list (using a list comprehension) and then printing that out:

```
print(*[i for i in range(3)], sep="\n")
```

You need the `sep` argument if you want them on a new line each; without it they'll be on one line, each separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the print statement there, it prints each of the value, then prints the list which has no values in it.

```
>>> this = print([(i) for i in range(3)])
[0, 1, 2]
>>> print(this)
None
>>>
```

This should show you the problem. What you want to use is

```
>>> [(i) for i in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
```